# Pressure jumps by $2\sigma/R$ across a curved liquid surface. Do temperature and chemical potential have similar jumps?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, surface-tension

We know that pressure under a curved surface of a liquid experiences a jump due to surface tension. One of the ways to derive this fact is through a thermodynamic argument. I was trying to apply a similar argument to chemical potential jump and temperature jump and it seemed to work (i.e. there is a jump of both quantities), but since I never hear of such jumps, I suspect there is a mistake. I wonder if anyone could point to a flaw in the logic or confirm that everything is correct. The derivation for the pressure usually looks like this:

**Pressure jump.**
Imagine a droplet of a radius $r$ in a saturated gas. If the system is kept at equilibrium, the Helmholtz free energy is minimized. Consider a small increase of the size of the droplet by a $\delta r$. The change of the free energy can be written as follows:
$$
\delta F=\sigma 8\pi r \delta r - 4\pi r^2 \delta r \Delta P,
$$
where $\Delta P$ is the pressure difference between the liquid and the gas. Since the system is at equilibrium $\delta F=0$, we obtain the difference in pressure $\Delta P=2\sigma/r$.

**Chemical potential drop**. We could perform the same trick with the number of particles and difference in chemical potential. Suppose we move some particles ($\delta N$) from the droplet in to the gas without changing the volume of the droplet. Since the droplet becomes less dense, the surface tension must change proportionally to the change of the density of the fluid
$$
\delta \sigma=\alpha \frac{\delta N}{\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3}
$$
and the total change of energy will be
$$
\delta F=\alpha \frac{\delta N}{\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3}4\pi r^2 - \delta N \Delta\mu
$$
Equating this quantity to zero yields
$$
\Delta\mu=\frac{3 \alpha}{r}.
$$
I.e. the chemical potential drop between the liquid and the gas is not zero. But I never heard of such drop. Does it really exist? Or did I do a mistake?

**Temperature drop**. Now the weirdest part. I would like to do a similar trick as for pressure and chemical potential, but I cannot do it through the Helmholz free energy and have to do it through regular energy. To get regular energy for the surface, we need to add $s AT$ ($s$ is the surface entropy density, A is the area of the surface and $T$ is the temperature) to the Hemholtz free energy, i.e. the energy of the surface is
$$
E_s=(\sigma+sT)A=\sigma_E A
$$
Now we can get back to transferring stuff from the droplet to the gas. This time we transfer entropy $\delta S$ from the droplet to the gas. Such transfer will cool down the droplet, which should change the surface tension by the amount proportional to the change in entropy density, i.e.
$$
\delta\sigma_E =\beta\frac{\delta S}{\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3}.
$$
The total change in the energy of the system is therefore
$$
\delta E=\beta \frac{\delta S}{\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3}4\pi r^2 - \delta S \Delta T,
$$
where $\Delta T$ is the temperature difference between the droplet and the environment. Equating $\delta E$ to $0$, we obtain
$$
\Delta T=\frac{3 \beta}{r}.
$$
Now, this completely *blows my mind* because I never heard that a system can have different temperatures at equilibrium in different parts. So there is probably a mistake in the derivation or I am missing something, but what could it be? May be $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are zero? But why?